# Gmaps4rails visualRefresh (Google maps)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Good day. Does somebody know how to turn on visualRefresh on gmaps4rails gem. I tried (for non static maps) to add &visual_refresh  = true as a URL parameter didn't work.

In docs is wroted to insert google.maps.visualRefresh=true; before map shows. But I have no idea where to put this line into gmaps4rails. Please help.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a day now as well. I've added the `google.maps.visualRefresh=true` in different places but it doesn't seem to take effect. When I do the same thing on a non gmaps4rails map, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the version of Google API currently used in Gmaps4Rails, which is currently set to 3.8 on the [latest gem](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/v1.5.6/lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb#L8) (v 1.5.6) and 3.9 on [master](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb#L8). I have opened a [pull request](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/pull/347) asking for the version to be updated to 3.12.

You could use my forked version and then make sure to set `google.maps.visualRefresh=true` on your page before the map gets rendered. E.g.

```
- content_for :scripts do
  :javascript
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
```

This could probably be further cleaned up by making it an option passed to the `gmaps` method call, but unfortunately at this time I don't have the bandwidth to do such a change.

Comment: Thanks for help and commit. Simple change but big effect.